# MySQL Query to retrieve relationship between you and a list of friends

Tags: mysql, sql

I would simply like to query my friends table for friends of a specific user, and then find out on that list of users, if they are my friends or not. The rows in the friends table is bidirectional, meaning that one row represents a relationship between 2 users.

These are the tables im using currently to get the list of friends for a specific user:

```
friends
-------
userId           *the user sending a friend request*
friendId         *the user receiving the friend request*
relationshipId   *an id for the relationship*
initiated_by     *the user initiating a friend request*
status           *whether or not the users are friends 'friends' or 'pending'*
```

```
users
-------
userId           *the userid of a user*
username         *the username of a user*
```

The current query I had got the list of friends for a specific user but didn't give me the relationship between myself and the list of those friends for that specific user:

```
SELECT B.userId, B.username, A.relationshipId, A.initiated_by, A.status FROM (SELECT userId, relationshipId, initiated_by, status FROM friends WHERE (friendId= 'insert_userId' AND status = 'friends') UNION SELECT friendId, relationshipId, initiated_by, status FROM friends WHERE (userId= 'insert_userId' AND status = 'friends')) A INNER JOIN users B USING (userId)
```

Sample date in the friends table:
[friends table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmGxo.png)

Expected outcome would just be the userId's of the friends of the specific user and their relationship with me (via status column)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.  Mixing the actual friends with the requests does not seem like a good idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Added!

Comment: In the 3d line of your expected output I don't see the id ending with `...9e2` which I assume is *your* id in any of the columns userid or friendid, so why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a self conditional join:

```
select f1.*, f2.status as mystatus
from friends f1 left join friends f2
on case when <otherid> = f1.userId then f1.friendId else f1.userId end = 
   case when <myid> = f2.userId then f2.friendId else f2.userId end
   and <myid> in (f2.userId, f2.friendId) 
where <otherid> in (f1.userId, f1.friendId)
and f1.status = 'friends'
```

Comment: this query only brought back one row that was common between the otherid friends and mine, I need the query to not only display the list of friends from the other user, but to tell me also if they are my friend or not

Comment: If these users are not in your friends list either 'friends' or 'pending' how would they be presented? You want results that include you either in the column userid or in the column friendid or not?

Comment: sorry I should have worded my response better: I want to be able to query the friends table to collect all of the rows that show a 'friends' status with the user I am querying with. and then with that list, I want to be able to find out if they are my 'friends', 'pending', or null

Answer (score 0):

You can get the other user's friends and use a `LEFT JOIN` to find out if they are also friends of yourself. For example:

```
select
  f.friendid,
  case when m.friendid is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end as also_my_friend
from friends f
left join friends m on m.friendid = f.friendid
                   and m.status = 'friends'
                   and m.userid = 456 -- my user id
where f.userid = 123 -- other user id
  and f.status = 'friends'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to find all the friends of a selected `@userIdToQuery`, and then from that user's friends, you want to see if you have any matching friends with your Id (or in the query below `@myId`)

I've used a CTE to get the selected users friends, then using those Ids to check against your friends..

```
WITH t1 AS
(
    -- This query gets the friends of the selected @userIdToQuery
    SELECT
    IF(userId = @userIdToQuery, friendId, userId) AS friendId,
    status
    FROM Friends
    WHERE (userId = @userIdToQuery OR friendId = @userIdToQuery)
    AND status = 'friends' 
)

SELECT
IF(userId = @myId, friendId, userId) AS friendId,
status
FROM friends
INNER JOIN t1 ON friendId = t1.friendId OR userId = t1.friendId
WHERE (userId = @myId OR friendId = @myId)
```

Or to do that without a CTE then this might work:

```
SELECT
IF(userId = @myId, friendId, userId) AS friendId, -- select the id that isn't our id
status -- select the status
FROM friends
INNER JOIN 
(
    -- This query gets the friends of the selected @userIdToQuery
    SELECT
    IF(userId = @userIdToQuery, friendId, userId) AS friendId
    FROM Friends
    WHERE (userId = @userIdToQuery OR friendId = @userIdToQuery)
    AND status = 'friends' 
) t1 ON t1.friendId = friends.friendId OR t1.friendId = friends.userId -- matching friends
WHERE (friends.userId = @myId OR friends.friendId = @myId) -- where one of the ids is 'us'
```

Comment: thanks! I tried querying that but I keep getting a syntax error near 't1 AS ( SELECT IF(userId = '28ce75d1-8848-49ee-ad20-4864b7b2d9e2', friendId, use' at line 1...pretty new to sql queries so no idea as to how to troubleshoot this

Comment: actually figured out why (maybe) I'm using MySQL version 5.6 and CTE only works with 8.0 and above

Comment: @narhc8 - ahh sorry. I'm more familiar with MS-SQL where CTEs are common. Try the revised example which doesn't need a CTE

Comment: thank you so much! okay so the second one works, but some of the fields are ambiguous to mysql so when I (tried) to specify it, it brought back rows but not the right ones...